# How to add live data to stacked bar chart

Tags: d3.js

I have a stacked bar chart, which gains data from an api.
It works fine when loaded, and the data is displayed as it should be.

Now I wish to add new data to the chart every ten minutes, calling the same API as when loaded, the chart should refresh asynchronously and he new data and axis label need to be updated as new data is gained.

What I have done so far..
https://plnkr.co/edit/s2Os8UlpSbCWlkNP6wuA?p=preview

```
var ma = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(parseDate(d.date)); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.ma); });
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use jquery, then you can send an AJAX request using the [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) `function`. Make sure you handle the response in the result's `done()` `function`, as `success` is deprecated.

Plain AJAX request example:

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Taken from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp). If you mastered AJAX requests, then the next step is to write a poller, using [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp). The first parameter should be a `function` which sends a request and the second should be the time between two execution in milliseconds (10000 in this case). Or you can use an existing poller. This is one I have implemented:

```
function Initializable(params) {
    this.initialize = function(key, def, private) {
        if (def !== undefined) {
            (!!private ? params : this)[key] = (params[key] !== undefined) ? params[key] : def;
        }
    };
}

function Poller(params) {
    Initializable.call(this, params);

    var that = this;
    this.initialize("url", window.location.href);
    this.initialize("interval", 5000);
    this.initialize("type", "POST");
    this.initialize("method", "POST");
    this.initialize("data", {});
    this.initialize("strict", true);

    var defaultFunction = function() {};

    this.initialize("done", defaultFunction);
    this.initialize("fail", defaultFunction);
    this.initialize("always", defaultFunction);

    this.isRunning = function() {
        return !!params.intervalID;
    };

    this.run = function() {
        if (this.strict && (this.green === false)) {
            return;
        }
        this.green = false;
        $.ajax({
            url: this.url,
            method: this.method,
            data: this.data
        }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            that.green = true;
            that.done(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            that.green = true;
            that.fail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }).always(function(param1, param2, param3) {
            that.green = true;
            that.always(param1, param2, param3);
        });
    };

    this.start = function() {
        if (!params.intervalID) {
            this.run();
            params.intervalID = setInterval(this.run.bind(this), this.interval);
        }
    };

    this.stop = function() {
        if (!!params.intervalID) {
            clearInterval(params.intervalID);
            params.intervalID = undefined;
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Can I kindly ask the downvoter to tell me why did he downvote my answer?